# Converting OpenCV C++ to C to wrap in python

Tags: python, c++, c, opencv

I am writing a wrapper for an imaging API in C++ (but exporting as a extern "C" to use with ctypes in python). When I try to build my .dll I get the following error:

> warning C4190: 'snapImage' has C-linkage specified, but returns UDT 'cv::Mat' which is incompatible with C

I am trying to return a opencv matrix that can be read into python, like so:

```
__declspec(dllexport) cv::Mat snapImage(bool* success)
{
    if(!pTransfer || !pBuffer)
    {
        if(success)
            *success = false;
        return cv::Mat();
    }

    bool ret = pTransfer->Snap() > 0;
    ret &= pTransfer->Wait(1000) > 0;
    void* data;
    ret &= pBuffer->GetAddress(&data) > 0;
    image->imageData = static_cast<char*>(data);
    cv::Mat frame(image);

    if(success)
        *success = ret;
    std::cout << cv::format(frame, "numpy") << std::endl;
    return frame;
}
```

I know that cvMat exists, so I am giving that a shot, but is there a way to allow for me to build this dll?

Thanks

Comment: you can't return a cv::Mat (a c++ object) in C. what exactly do you need opencv for here ? also, ctypes and opencv/c++ do not go well

Comment: also, you might want to hook into numpy directly instead (the images used in cv2 are numpy arrays, not cv::Mat)

Comment: @berak What is a good way of doing that? I am trying to get a frame from a camera (which is low level C with a C++ wrapper). I am trying to get an array or matrix from this C program to python via ctypes.

Comment: never used ctypes, sorry, but current opencv is probably a bad choice for that. too much overhead for a simple bridge.

Comment: hmm, perhaps just sending it to a c array?

Comment: again, consider numpy arrays being the 'lingua franca' for image processing in python.